# Get specific property name in an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a newbie to react. I have an object. I am trying to get specific value in an object but I am unable to do so. In my case, I am finding the value "Miami, USA" in the description of startLocation. The data object is retrieved from the server through api request and redux action.

```
1)Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys { description, address}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
2)Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
```

The data I got back from server looks like this,

```
{
   "startLocation": {
   "description": "Miami, USA",
   "address": "301 Biscayne Blvd, Miami, FL 33132, USA"
   },
   "name": "Running",
   "description": "something",    // not this one
}
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Page.css';
    
class Page extends Component {
  // some code      
  render() {
     const eventData = this.props.events.data;

     const {
         name,
         startLocation,
         description,
     } = eventData;
            
    console.log(startLocation["description"]) // undefined
         
    return (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="heading-group">
            <h1 className="header">
              <span>{name}</span>
            </h1>
                            
            <span className="header-text">
              {startLocation["description"]}>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
       )
      }
    }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    events: state.eventContainer,
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
)(Page);
```

Any idea?

Comment: Were is eventOne defined in you second snippet?

Comment: Perhaps the data is undefined the first time the component renders.

Comment: Heads up, using modules `const eventOne = {` doesn't create a global object.   If the file this is defined in is say called static.  Do -> `export const eventOne = {`  and then in you second snippet, do => `import {eventOne} from "./static"`

Comment: Actually, the data is retrieved from the server through redux action and api request. But somehow I am unable to destructure it. I've uploaded more details in my question.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with the sample data provided. Perhaps your `eventData` hasn't imported properly.

```js
const eventOne = {
       "startLocation": {
           "description": "Miami, USA",
            "address": "301 Biscayne Blvd, Miami, FL 33132, USA"
        },
       "name": "Running",
       "description": "something",
    }
     // destructure object javascript here
     const {
             name,
             startLocation,
             description,
         } = eventOne;
    
   console.log(description);
   console.log(startLocation);
   console.log(startLocation["description"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually, the data is retrieved from the server through redux action and api request. But somehow I am unable to destructure it. I've uploaded more details in my question.

Comment: @KK28 You should try `console.log(this.props.events.data)` to verify whether it has value or not? Besides, `this.props.events.data` should have `description` property then you can destructure it.